# Turn of Automatic Xml Formating in Asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a .net webservice that returns a string, I want the string representation returned bare and not wrapped up as xml.
for example:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Enroll()
{
   return "You are welcome";
}
```

The response I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://somenamespace/">
   You are welcome
  </string>
```

The response I prefer to get is simply:

```
You are welcome
```

How can I get this to happen without resorting to using a generic handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this out of the box, since the idea of web services is to use the XML for interoperability and consistency. (eg a Windows OS web service can talk to a Linux web service and understand what was returned).

Have a look at this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/963809.aspx).